# strong law of large numbers when mean goes to infinity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables with mean $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sqrt{n}$. I am a bit confused about using the strong law of large numbers (SLLN) in this case, because $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sqrt{n}$ goes to infinity as $n\to\infty$. I wonder if the assumptions of SLLN holds here and whether we can conclude that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n} \to \infty
$$
almost surely or not?
I appreciate any response/comment.

Answer (score 2):

The strong law of large numbers requires that you have an *infinite* sequence of random variables, from which you can average any number of terms you like. This gives us an infinite sequence
$$
   X_1, \frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}, \frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}{3}, \dots
$$
and the strong law of large numbers is about the limit of this sequence.

Here, you have a finite sequence of random variables, and you aren't just extending it as you increase $n$: if you change $n$, the distributions also change, because the expected value changes. So the strong law of large numbers doesn't apply to this situation.

For an example where the **conclusion** also does not hold, suppose that each of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is $n^2$ with probability $\frac1{n\sqrt n}$ and $0$ otherwise. Then with probability $(1 - \frac1{n \sqrt n})^n \ge 1 - \frac1{\sqrt n}$, we have $X_1 = X_2 = \dots = X_n = 0$. As a result, $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$ converges in probability to $0$, not $\infty$. (It does not almost surely converge to anything because, in particular, we don't have a common sample space for different values of $n$.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree, when we change $n$, the distribution changes. However, for any fixed $n$, we have a sequence of iid random variables. Is there any variant of the SLLN or other theorem that can tell something about the limiting distribution of the above sequence? Thanks again.

Comment: For example does the following makes sense: Suppose in addition we have Var$[X_i]= \sigma/n$. Define $Y_i = \frac{X_i}{ \sqrt{n} }$.  Then $E [Y_i] = 1$ and Var$[Y_i]=\sigma$. Hence, $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ is an infinite sequence of iid random variables. Using SLLN we conclude $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{n} \to E[Y_i]=1$. Hence $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n \sqrt{n}  } \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. From this, can we conclude that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n   } \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: This is still not an infinite sequence; what is $Y_{n+1}$?

Comment: $Y_{n+1} = \frac{X_{n+1}}{  \sqrt{n+1} }$. We also have E$[Y_{n+1}]=1$ and Var$[Y_{n+1}]=\sigma$.

Comment: There's no such thing as $X_{n+1}$, though! The $X_i$ only go up to $n$. Anyway, I've also added an example where the conclusion you want doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.